# php html Why isn't my form showing on the webpage?

Tags: php, html, web

I simply cannot understand how and why I am not seeing a form, when opening my site??? I wan a form consisting of bot username, password and a subit box to appear, though I don't see the solution here...

A solution and explaining would be much appreciated.

```
  <?php
   error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
   session_start();
   ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- 
-->
   <html>
   <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>World Talk Login</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <?php
    $form = "<form action='./login.php' method='post'>
   <table>
   <tr>
   <td>Username:</td>
   <td><input type='text' name='user'/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
  <td>Password:</td>
  <td><input type='password' name='password'/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td><input type='submit' name='loginbtn' value='Login'/></td>

  </tr>
  </table>
  </form>";            

  if ($_POST['loginbtn']){
  $user = $_POST ['user'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];

  if ($user) {
  if ($password){
  echo "$user - $password <hr /> $form";
  }
  else
  echo "You must enter your password. $form";
 }
 else
 echo "You must enter your username. $form";
 }
 ?>

</body>
</html>
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: You haven't closed off all of your  if statements. And your else statements are not being opened.

Comment: Actually looking at it a bit closer your if statements do not make sense. I am just fixing it. someone my beat me to it though :-P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your php at the bottom to the following.

```
if ($_POST['loginbtn']){
    $user = $_POST ['user'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if($user != "" && $password != "") {
        echo "$user - $password <hr /> $form";
    }

    if($user == "") {
        $error .= "You must enter your username.</br>";
    }

    if($password == "") {
        $error .= "You must enter your password.";
    }

    if($error != "") {
        echo $error.$form;
    }
} else {
    echo $form;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't print your form from PHP or mistakenly wrapped your form in PHP. It was wrapped around the `<?php` tag in the variable `$form` but no print to screen.

This is how it should look like below with errors working correctly ;-)

```
 <?php
   ini_set('display_errors', 1);
   ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   session_start();
   ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--

-->
   <html>
   <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>World Talk Login</title>
   </head>
   <body>

   <form action='./login.php' method='post'>
   <table>
   <tr>
   <td>Username:</td>
   <td><input type='text' name='user'/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
  <td>Password:</td>
  <td><input type='password' name='password'/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td><input type='submit' name='loginbtn' value='Login'/></td>

  </tr>
  </table>
  </form>

<?php

  if ($_POST['loginbtn']){
  $user = $_POST ['user'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];

  if ($user) {
  if ($password){
  echo "$user - $password <hr /> $form";
  }
  else
  echo "You must enter your password. $form";
 }
 else
 echo "You must enter your username. $form";
 }
 ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Now the form will always display :(  I think the OP meant to put the form inside a variable because the $form is at the end of the echo statements.

Comment: @Phil_1984_ Cheers, I must misread it wrong (to be fair it's not that difficult). To be honest I don't know why I bother with these ones because they only seem to take the code and run.

Answer (score 0):

you also didn't echo out your variable

Comment: This is actually the best answer. HAHA

Answer (score 0):

```
 <html>
   <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>World Talk Login</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <?php
    $form = "<form action='./login.php' method='post'>
   <table>
   <tr>
   <td>Username:</td>
   <td><input type='text' name='user'/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
  <td>Password:</td>
  <td><input type='password' name='password'/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td><input type='submit' name='loginbtn' value='Login'/></td>

  </tr>
  </table>
  </form>";

  echo $form;


  if (!isset($_POST['loginbtn'])){
  $user = (!isset($_POST['user']));
  $password = (!isset($_POST['password']));
}
  else{

  }

  ?>

</body>
</html>
```